# Using existing gas connection for new gas range?

Tags: appliances, installation, stove, range

I would like to connect a [regular GE gas stove like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB1w6.png) to a connector that was used by a Vulcan residential gas range (similar to [the one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duCXe.png))

Here is some information on the existing connector:

This is the pipe that supplies the gas to the Vulcan range.
[image]

This pipe has a nut attached to it. I unscrewed it and took pictures of it:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What would I need to do to use this existing gas connection with this [regular GE gas stove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB1w6.png)?

Is it something that I can do?

Comment: more than likely, what does the gas connection look like?

Comment: Considering what might go wrong compared to the cost of hiring a licensed professional installer is this really something you want to do?

Comment: You'll need to decide on that yourself. Basically, the connection is made using a  yellow (usually) flex pipe from the existing gas pipe valve to the appliance. It isn't hard or complex, but is does need to be done just right. Also, some localities may prohibit installation of gas appliances by non-licensed persons. You should check the procedure on a home site or look at a you-tube video to see if that is something within your comfort zone and also make sure that you're even permitted to install it yourself.

Comment: Fitting size is important as well.  It's basically as easy as @Ring suggests _if_ the fittings are all the right size.  If you get into having to change fittings, that can get a lot more complicated.

Comment: Aside from the risk/benefit equation, once you investigate the required connections involved between the two stoves (which can only be done after moving the old stove out), you must factor in your time for at least 1 trip to the hardware store (usually more than one) as part of your DIY cost. then you should replace all of the flexible connections, do NOT re-use older flexible connectors because they can crack when you pull the old stove out away from the wall after sitting still for so long. There may also be code changes from how the new connections must be done vs when the old one was done.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, You're right to point that out. If the supply fitting was had been wrong, I'd not have even tried.

Comment: @J.Raefield, If I'm shifting stoves, that isn't so much an issue. I can look at fittings when I move the stove. Move residential units have a standard fitting (1/2 inch flare? It's been a long time since I did my stove).

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a very simple job, if you can change a car tire this would be easier.  The basics are proper sealing compounds or tape at the joints, usually 2 adjustable wrenches or a pipe wrench and an adjustable wrench are the only tools needed. And last a bubble leak solution to check the new connections.

Some fittings use special pipe tape it is yellow or an approved for gas pipe dope going from pipe to the flair fitting.  After leak checking your fittings I will literally a match at a burner and turn it on, it may take a minute for the air to be purged from the lines, once a burner lights I do the others and the oven. I do the oven last because many of the ones I have had use a hot surface ignition and I like to reduce the amount of time that is firing. 
It really not difficult at all. Using the proper gas rated flex pipe and make sure the fittings are the correct size is critical. Depending on your connection to the gas system you may not need any sealant at all. It could be flair fittings then being clean and following the instructions like hand tight and 1/4 additional turn then checking for leaks. It is quite simple but some basic safety checks are important.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, I think I have that stove! The oven light went out after 2 months otherwise it's working well.

However you cannot seal gas connections with teflon tape or anything else but special gas-certified sealer, which looks like yellow mud. [See this image 1](http://www.handymanhowto.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Apply-Pipe-Sealant-to-Black-Iron-Nipple-Fitting-for-Natural-Gas-Shutoff-Valve.jpg).

1. Get a flexible connector to go from the stove to the gas wall connection.
2. Use proper sealer for gas on the joints and screw together.
3. Check for leaks on every joint very carefully by using a soapy water mixture. Paint the soapy water on with a new paintbrush. If you see bubbles forming you have a leak. Either tighten the threads or unscrew and add more sealer compound.